# Why fopen failed with folder?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, file

This code works.

```
pFile = fopen("d:\myfile.txt", "w");
```

This code doesn't work.

```
pFile = fopen("d:\ABC\myfile.txt", "w");
```

I do have this folder d:\ABC

O.S is Windows 10, using visual studio 2019.

errno is 22.

Comment: Did you check the permissions? What was the error code returned?

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: errno is 22 ....

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the \ in the strings like `"d:\\ABC...."`? Probably `\A` is an escape sequence and `\m` not.

Comment: What does `printf("%s\n", strerror(22));` report? What is the error message on Windows?  (On a Mac and on Linux, it is `EINVAL — Invalid argument`; that isn't necessarily what it translates to on Windows, though.) You could also try: `printf("name: [[%s]]\n", "d:\ABC\myfile.txt");` and see what it gives you. The chances are high that the backslashes have been 'removed'. You should consider `printf("name: [[%s]]\n", "d:\\ABC\\myfile.txt");` or even `printf("name: [[%s]]\n", "d:/ABC/myfile.txt");`. The Windows program APIs accept slashes in file names; it's the command prompt that dislikes them.

Comment: I only know \n is changing to a new line, what is \m?

Comment: @Mark IMKOn there is no `\m` escape sequence, anyway you don't need to care, the only thing that is important is that if you want to have a `'\'` in a string literal, you need to escape it by putting another backslash: e.g: `"Hello\\World"`;

Answer (score 0):

```
//these are all the same
char test1[]={'\n', '\a','\t','\\','\'','\"','\0'};
char test2[]={'\N', '\A','\T','\\','\'','\"','\0'};
char test3[]={10,7,9,92,39,34,0};
char test4[]={0x0a,0x07,0x09,0x5c,0x27,0x22,0x00};
char test5[]="\n\a\t\\\'\"";
char test6[]="\N\A\T\\\'\"";
```

microsoft file using

"d:\\ABC\\myfile.txt";

"d:/ABC/myfile.txt";

Answer (score -1):

This line solved the problem:

```
pFile = fopen("D:\ABC\\myfile.txt", "r");
```

Comment: You should escape both `\\` in that string.

Comment: or - even better - change the backslash characters to forward slashes. Windows is perfectly able to cope with that. It is less error prone and more portable.

Comment: @mrfo, in most cases forward slash works, except "\\?\" paths are only special cased to bypass normalization (to sidestep `MAX_PATH`) if the prefix uses only backslash, in which case the rest of the path must also use only backslash. Also, and a bit tangential, if [`NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw) is defined, `CreateProcess` requires backslash in a relative path such as "ABC\\myfile.exe" in `lpCommandLine`; it won't find "ABC/myfile.exe".